# Is it possible to define custom technical indicators, that takes 2 series as input?

Tags: highcharts, indicator

I have a highstocks chart that shows trends of non stock data because it has some good features that our product needs.
one of these features is custom technical indicators, espcially between 2 different trends showing.
I know how to define maually an indicator, but it seems I can't use more then 1 series with it, while I want to create indicators for a veraity of differneces between 2 or more series. 
I can't find a way to do this, so I'm wondering if it is at all possible

Comment: Could you prepare an example of your chart? What indicator do you want to present?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rabigado/7wousgm5/ this is a sample of a chart I might display
and I would love to have an indicator that shows an average beetween the 2 of them(or of I have another series any 2 series the user chooses) with parameters the user control that add some noise reduction

Answer (score 0):

Average between two series can be simply added as another separate series. You can use for example load event to calculate it and `chart.addSeries()` method to add it.

Code:

```
chart: {
  zoomType: 'xy',
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var chart = this,
        dataLen = chart.series[0].points.length,
        newSeries = {
          id: "avg",
          name: "average",
          data: []
        },
        series1 = chart.series[0],
        series2 = chart.series[1],
        i;

      for (i = 0; i < dataLen; i++) {
        newSeries.data.push({
          x: series1.points[i].x,
          y: (series2.points[i].y + series1.points[i].y) / 2
        })
      }

      chart.addSeries(newSeries);
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/15sa38qb/

**API:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeries